# Angular Material form-field input label positioning

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have the following input field in one of my projects. I have added the +94 as a prefix to the input field. Now, when I click on the input field, the position of the label (Your Mobile Number) that is on top of the input is overlapped by the input field border. How do I fix it? I would like to pull that label towards the left side as there is more space.

[image]

Comment: Share your code